# what is the exact use of Stuff in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In my stored procedure I have a statement like this

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype) from VType_tbl
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')
```

i dont know what exactly would happen with these statement?  why we are using `Stuff`
 and `QUOTENAME` and `;`  for `XML PATH`

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Comment: could you please give any website address for study all the basic and advanced things in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The STUFF function inserts a string into another string. It deletes a
>   specified length of characters in the first string at the start
>   position and then inserts the second string into the first string at
>   the start position.

**Syntax**

```
STUFF ( character_expression , start , length , replaceWith_expression )
```

**Example**

```
SELECT STUFF('abcdef', 2, 3, 'ijklmn');
GO
```

**Result**

> aijklmnef

[Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: oh,,i got it ,,thanks sir,,could you please give any website address for study all the basic and advanced things in sql server

Comment: There are different site available with these information. All you need is to search. You may try this :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/bb895927 as a start ;)

Answer (score 1):

The stuff command removes the first character and replaces it with ''.

Exploring the stuff string function (http://craftydba.com/?p=5397).

```
-- This snippet from my blog results in pay attention!
SELECT 
    STUFF('Pay no attention to the man behind the curtain!', 
          4, 3, '') as oz_quote;
```